# PDO PHP ORACLE connection

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

heres my code

```
$database = ' 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.8.28)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
   )';


    $db = new PDO('oci:dbname='.$database, 'middleuser', '1');


    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * from BD_CENTERDEPT');
    $sth->execute();

    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {  

        echo $row->NAME."\n";  

    }
```

no error shown, but why? i am using oracle instant client.
i already created a path in environmental variables "C:\xampp\instantclient_12_1"

and already uncomment "extension=php_pdo_oci.dll" in my php.ini
iam pretty sure that

BD_CENTERDEPT has NAME column and data on it.

no errors but no data shown? how do I know if I really connected to oracle database?

Comment: Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very begin of your script.

Comment: There are possible things you need to do, not just about doing programming. How about Pinging 192.168.8.28? also check if the ports really accessible by using Query Tools of oracle. If so then how about the instantiation of PDO class? there might be a problem...

Answer (score -1):

Yay i forgot the database name in my query :) must be

```
$db->prepare('SELECT * from dbname.BD_CENTERDEPT')
```